# Converting binary to decimal using only Boolean and logic comparisons

Tags: python

I am taking a Python Certification class and have taken two practice exams to prepare for the timed exam I will be scheduling soon.  However, there is limited interaction with professors and the discussion board is mostly students.  I have a question that has been on both practice exams, so I imagine it will be on the real exam as well, and I can not see to wrap my head around how to solve it.  There is no way in the class to see how to solve coding problems you have gotten incorrect, which is a major disappointment as that helps me in the future.  I know there are built in functions for solving binary/decimal conversions, but the professor is wanting this done using Boolean logic and numerical comparisons as we are still in the early stages of the course.  If anyone could assist in "walking" through the why's of the answer I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you.

> number = 1101
>
> You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them! When you
> Submit your code, we'll change these lines to assign different values
> to the variables.
>
> The number above represents a binary number. It will always be up to
> eight digits, and all eight digits will always be either 1 or 0.
>
> The string gives the binary representation of a number. In binary,
> each digit of that string corresponds to a power of
> 2. The far left digit represents 128, then 64, then 32, then 16, then 8, then 4, then 2, and then finally 1 at the far right.
>
> So, to convert the number to a decimal number, you want to (for
> example) add 128 to the total if the first digit is 1, 64 if the
> second digit is 1, 32 if the third digit is 1, etc.
>
> For example, 00001101 is the number 13: there is a 0 in the 128s
> place, 64s place, 32s place, 16s place, and 2s place. There are 1s in
> the 8s, 4s, and 1s place. 8 + 4 + 1 = 13.
>
> Note that although we use 'if' a lot to describe this problem, this
> can be done entirely boolean logic and numerical comparisons.
>
> Print the number that results from this conversion.

Comment: Your effort here is to figure out how numbers from the binary system are transformed into decimal ones. This concept is described well in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
number = "00001101" #in Python, leading zeros are not permitted, so use a string
total = 0 #this var will keep track of the number in decimal form
index = len(number)-1 #eg 1100 has 4 digits and the max power is 3, 2^3.

for str_digit in number: #for each digit (as a string) in the number,
    #total += int(str_digit)* 2**index #add the value (0 or 1) multiplied by 2 raised to the index power
    if int(str_digit): #either 'if 0' or 'if 1'
        total += 2**index #add 2 raised to the index power
    index -= 1 # decrease the index
print(total)
```

Note that the line `if int(str_digit):` is actually redundant if you use the commented line `total += int(str_digit)* 2**index` instead, but I included it because your question specified that you want to test the Boolean value.

This line is the same as `if 0:` or `if 1:` which is the same as `if False:` or `if True:`.

Comment: Nice comments to explain your program to OP.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.  I am a very visual learner and all of the theoretical jargon confounds me unless I can see it in action at the same time.  I will give this a shot when I get home from work today and walk my way through the lines of code.  The biggest hiccup on these problems is the constant adjustment necessary as your current results affect your previous and then it all ties together.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps and good luck learning Python! If this answer helped, would appreciate it if you could mark it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is this:

```py
int(number, base=2)
```

Comment: yes, I read about the int() and bin() functions for easy conversions, but as we have not covered those easier methods I am reluctant to utilize them in these questions.  THank you for the information though